# How to unable Enable bing spell checker in Luis?

Tags: c#, azure-language-understanding

I am facing the issue with the spell checker option in LUIS, As i am checked it and published. When i see again its showing as unchecked. I had purchased Bing spell check key too.

Please help me with this...

Answer (score 1):

Now users aren't required to purchase a Bing Spell Check Key to use the Bing Spell Check API with your LUIS model. To enable spellcheck, you go to the publish page of your LUIS App:

[image]

After you get here and publish your app, you'll find near the center-bottom of the page you will see your region and an endpoint (*regions* and *endpoints* if this app is publicly accessible, meaning other users can use their own subscription key to use your LUIS model) along with several checkboxes:

[image]

The bing spell checker is unchecked, but one thing to note is that if you have not enabled it before, it is *already implicitly enabled for your LUIS app*. This means that your LUIS application already uses the Bing Spell Check API. When you check the box, LUIS will add `&spellCheck=true` to app's endpoint(s):

[image]

If you uncheck the box, then the endpoint(s) will have **`&spellCheck=false`** instead of `&spellCheck=true`, see the screencap below:

[image]

Comment: We did same things, but When I publish again refresh the page-->Enable bing spell checker become unchecked.

Comment: When looking at the endpoint, does it still say `&spellCheck=true`?

Comment: This is actually by design, with the idea that once you set up your endpoint and copy/paste it into your application, you're set. When revisiting the publish page, though the currently listed endpoint(s) doesn't have the same settings as the first one, the fact that the currently listed endpoint(s) are different doesn't have any bearing on how your stored endpoint (and therefore LUIS App) operates.